# Working with a big csv in python

Tags: python, csv, numpy, pandas

I've got a big table in a csv file, which has 5 million rows and 4 columns.
My objective is to take each row from the first 500k and to compare it with all the following rows (i.e. 5kk - n) based on certain condition. The condition is something like

row(n).column1 == row(n+1).column1 AND row(n).column2 == row(n+1).column2 AND     row(n).column3 == row(n+1).column3

OR

row(n).column1 == row(n+1).column1 AND row(n).column2 == row(n+1).column2 AND 
row(n+1).column4.split()[0] in row(n).column4

Now I'm using simple loop over lists:

```
for idx,i in enumerate(big[:500000]):
    for jdx,j in enumerate(big):
        if (jdx>idx and i[0]==j[0] and i[1]==j[1] and i[2]==j[2]) or (i[0]==j[0] and i[1]==j[1] and j[3].split()[0] if j[3].split() else '' in i[3]):
            matches.append([idx,jdx])
```

Which obviously takes very long time to complete (about a week using single proccess).
Pandas and numpy are good for operations on the whole array at a time, but I don't know if I can convert this task into them somehow.

So the question is, how can I speed up the proccess?

Comment: Look at [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift)

Comment: You are executing something like 1.2 trillion if-statements. Since you have the whole data set in primary memory, I/O shouldn't be a problem. If it takes a week, then you execute approximately 2 million if-statements per second, which sounds like a pretty good speed. I wonder how much faster it would be, even if the whole loop is written in C?

Comment: It probably won't change execution time but - you could refactor the terms in the logic statement: ```if i[0]==j[0] and i[1]==j[1] and ((jdx>idx and i[2]==j[2]) or (j[3].split()[0] if j[3].split() else '' in i[3]))```

Comment: Avoid this condition by generating indexes in the correct range: jdx > idx. That will save a bit of wasted time.

Comment: @EdChum I don't understand how shift will help here.

Comment: @Moose I will try to rewrite it in Cython, and see what happens.

Comment: shift allows you to compare whole arrays against a shifted row, what you are doing could be done very quickly using numpy or pandas, for example you could take a slice of your data (imported into numpy or pandas) and then filter them using your criteria as all you are doing is looking for matches between 3 consecutive rows

Comment: Good spotting by arhuaco. If you do 'for idx,i in enumerate(big[:500000]): for jdx,j in enumerate(**big[idx:**]):' you will cut the number of iterations.

Comment: @Moose In this case slicing on the fly is actually slower.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do something with sorting the data. 1) Could you give a few rows of the CSV file? 2) Could you clarify the  conditions? Ie. it's not clear to me what you mean by `n` and `n+1`.

Comment: You can create a hash1 and hash2 fields which are hashed combinations of the comparison fields (e.g. hash1 is f(column1,column2,column3), and hash2 is f(column1,column2,column4). Then the comparisions become much faster and simplier to see if hash1[n] == hash1[n+1] etc.

Comment: @moarningsun I've already cut the initial table and dropped all unnecessary rows and columns. The data is actually sorted by date, from present to past. So the first rows are from 2014 and the last are from 1970-s. I need to take each row from the first 4 years (about 500k lines) and check it against all rows that are older.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using following things to improve performance.

1. Separated loop in a function (about 20% gain)
2. Improved logical operations.
3. Used PyPy interpreter (300+% increase)